# Can I add 6GB RAM of these modules to my existing RAM config?

Tags: memory, motherboard, windows-10-preview, sdram

After a crash of my PC I decided to reinstall the machine with Windows 10. Everything is running fine, but I notice that the 6GB is a bit too tight for all the software I'm running.

Since this is an old PC and I'm planning on buying a new one in the future, I'd like to add some RAM but not spend a fortune on it.

The motherboard is an MSI MSI X58 Pro-E and there are 6 slots with 3 RAM sticks installed of type Kingston DDR3-1333 PC3-10600 SDRAM. I found some Kingston ValueRAM 2 GB DDR3-1333 sticks online. Would these fit this motherboard? I'm guessing this would be fine, but I'd like to make sure before I order them.

Thanks for any info you might have!

Comment: Try Hardware recommendations, https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ . That said, use Kingston's online guide to buy RAM.

Comment: One note; there are some risks to installing even seemingly identical RAM chips from multiple retail packages. Over-clockers especially recommend purchasing all the RAM in a single package, so that the chips are all factory-tested together. I know, rebuying the RAM you already have far from optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It Should** I would update the BIOS also, if you have not.
The 1333 is the speed.

**MSI Motherboard  X58 Pro-E**

Max memory 24 Gigabytes

> Supports six unbuffered DIMM of 1.5 Volt DDR3 800/1066/1333*/1600* (OC) DRAM, 24GB Max
>
> - Supports 1Gb/ 2Gb/ 4Gb DRAM size
> - Supports x8 / x16 data lines per DIMM
> - Supports up to 3 channel mode

**BIOS version 8.E**

> Release Date: 2010-11-02
> File Size 1.27 MB
> Description
>
> - Update CPU Microcode.
> - Improved memory compatibility.
> - Support OCZ PCIE SSD memory card.
>   [7522v8E.zip](https://download.msi.com/bos_exe/mb/7522v8E.zip)

**Manual**

> Language English
> File Size 11.42 MB
> [E7522v3.1.zip](https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/E7522v3.1.zip)

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are NON-ECC with the other specs you mentioned and the correct pin count you should be fine.  That x58 motherboard will probably give you another 10 years, especially if you throw a xeon x5690 in there and boot from a SSD.  12GB of ram from 6 will be around perfect for that machine.